# Summarizing redundant SQL information

Tags: sql, oracle11g, group-by

Given (Oracle 11g):

```
MANUFACTURER
------------
ID
NAME

CARS
---------
CAR_ID
MANUFACTURER_ID
NAME

PARTS
---------
PART_ID
CAR_ID
PART_NAME
```

Is it possible from SQL to get a listing of parts by car and manufacturer in a single query without repeating the redundant data on each row?

Something like:

```
FORD         ESCORT         Windshield Wiper
                            Horn
                            Steering Wheel
             F-150          Windshield Wiper
                            Horn
                            Bed Liner
TOYOTA       CAMRY          Floor Mat
                            Door Handle
             CIVIC          Headlight
                            Horn
```

Or does something like this require application-level logic and/or use of reporting features. I've tried numerous queries, but gotten nothing close thus far.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `lag` function like this:

```
WITH manufacturer AS (
SELECT 1 manufacturer_id, 'FORD' NAME FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'TOYOTA' FROM dual)
, CAR AS (
SELECT 1 car_id, 1 manufacturer_id, 'ESCORT' AS name FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 1, 'F-150' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 2, 'CAMRY' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 2, 'CIVIC' FROM dual)
, part AS (
SELECT 1 AS part_id, 1 AS car_id, 'Windshield Wiper' AS part_name FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 1, 'Horn' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 1, 'Steering Wheel' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 2, 'Windshield Wiper' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 2, 'Horn' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 6, 2, 'Bed Liner' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 7, 3, 'Floor Mat' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 8, 3, 'Door Handle' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 9, 4, 'Headlight' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 10, 4, 'Horn' FROM dual)
SELECT case lag (m.name) over (order by p.part_id)
            when m.name then null
            else m.name
       end as manufcturer,
       case lag (c.name) over (order by p.part_id)
            when c.name then null
            else c.name
       end as carname,
       p.part_name
  FROM manufacturer m INNER JOIN car c ON m.manufacturer_id = c.manufacturer_id
        INNER JOIN part p ON p.car_id = c.car_ID
;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
MANUFACTURER  CARNAME   PART_NAME
------------- --------- -----------------
FORD          ESCORT    Windshield Wiper
                        Horn
                        Steering Wheel
              F-150     Windshield Wiper
                        Horn
                        Bed Liner
TOYOTA        CAMRY     Floor Mat
                        Door Handle
              CIVIC     Headlight
                        Horn
```

Answer (score 1):

The natural way to get the result is:

```
select m.name as manufacturer_name, c.name as car_name, p.name as part_name
from manufacturer m join
     cars c
     on c.manufacturer_id = m.id join
     parts p
     on p.car_id = c.car_id;
```

This will be in a format where all the cells are filled in the table (so `'Ford'` will be in the first few rows of the table).

If you only want the first appearance of each name, you can use `row_number()` (and be sure to sort the results in the end):

```
select (case when m_seqnum = 1 then manufacturer_name else '' end) as manufacturer_name,
       (case when c_seqnum = 1 then car_name else '' end) as car_name,
       part_name
from (select m.name as manufacturer_name, c.name as car_name, p.name as part_name,
             row_number() over (partition by m.name order by c.name, p.name) as m_seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by m.name, c.name order by p.name) as c_seqnum
      from manufacturer m join
           cars c
           on c.manufacturer_id = m.id join
           parts p
           on p.car_id = c.car_id
     ) mcp
order by manufacturer_name, car_name, part_name;
```

Comment: +1 Good use of `row_number()` and the clarification of the first query.